# Salesforce Community custom login in mobile is not working properly

Tags: community

I am using SF Community for native iOS/Android app. I created my community so that I could registered/logged in community via my desktop browser. I also configured enpoint for iOS/Android after that I have logged in SF Community via my mobile. I used this function:

> SFAuthenticationManager.sharedManager().loginWithCompletion({
>   (oAuthInfo : SFOAuthInfo!) -> Void in
>               self.setupRootViewController()
>           }, failure: { (oAuthInfo : SFOAuthInfo!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
>               SFAuthenticationManager.sharedManager().logout()
>           })

But the problem is the webview keeps opening the start url (chatter page) after login successfull. The completion closure is never called. I don't know how to fix it. I think I missed something or did wrong. Could anyone please let me know how can I fix it?[image]